# Add column with closest vaues to PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe (say `df`) which has two columns ( `Name` and `Score`). Following is an example of the dataframe:

```
+------+-----+
|  Name|Score|
+------+-----+
| name1|11.23|
| name2|14.57|
| name3| 2.21|
| name4| 8.76|
| name5|18.71|
+------+-----+
```

I have a numpy array (say `bin_array`) which has values close to the numerical values that are there in the column titled `Score` of the PySpark dataframe.

Following is the aforementioned numpy array:

```
bin_array = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20])
```

I want to **compare value from each row of the column `Score` with values in `bin_array` and store the closest value (gotten from `bin_array`) in a separate column in the PySpark dataframe.**

Below is how I would like my new dataframe (say `df_new`) to look.

```
+------+-----+------------+
|  Name|Score| Closest_bin|
+------+-----+------------+
| name1|11.23|      10.0  |
| name2|14.57|      15.0  |
| name3| 2.21|       0.0  |
| name4| 8.76|      10.0  |
| name5|18.71|      20.0  |
+------+-----+------------+
```

I have the below mentioned function which gives me the closest values from `bin_array`. The function works fine when I test it with individual numbers.

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return float(array[idx])
```

In my actual work, I will have millions of rows in the datafrmae. **What is the most efficient way to create `df_new`?**

Following are the steps that I tried to use to create user-defined function (udf) and the new data frame (`df_new`).

```
closest_bin_udf = F.udf( lambda x: find_nearest(array, x) )
df_new = df.withColumn( 'Closest_bin' , closest_bin_udf(df.Score)  )
```

But, I got errors when I tried `df_new.show()`. A portion of the error is shown below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-685c9b7e25d9> in <module>()
----> 1 df_new.show()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    376         """
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    379         else:
    380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
```

You can use the below mentioned steps to create the aforementioned dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

Stats = Row("Name", "Score")

stat1 = Stats('name1', 11.23)
stat2 = Stats('name2', 14.57)
stat3 = Stats('name3', 2.21)
stat4 = Stats('name4', 8.76)
stat5 = Stats('name5', 18.71)

stat_lst = [stat1 , stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5]
df = spark.createDataFrame(stat_lst)

df.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`bucketizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer) from `pyspark.mllib`

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

Stats = Row("Name", "Score")

stat_lst = [Stats('name1', 11.23) , Stats('name2', 14.57), Stats('name3', 2.21), Stats('name4', 8.76), Stats('name5', 18.71)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(stat_lst)

from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

"""
Bucketizer creates bins like 0-5:0, 5-10:1, 10-15:2, 15-20:3
As I see, your expected output wants the closest numbered bin, so you might 
have to change your buckets or the variable `t` below accordingly.
"""
bucket_list = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]

bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=bucket_list, inputCol="Score", outputCol="buckets")
df_buck = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(df)

df_buck.show()
```

I am still working on getting the closest bin, I'll update my answer.

If you want your array values for each bucket you can use udf to create a new column with bucket names

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

t = dict(zip(range(len(bucket_list)), bucket_list))
udf_foo = udf(lambda x: t[x], IntegerType())
df_buck = df_buck.withColumn("score_bucket", udf_foo("buckets"))
```

### Output

```
>>> df_buck.show()

+-----+-----+-------+------------+
| Name|Score|buckets|score_bucket|
+-----+-----+-------+------------+
|name1|11.23|    2.0|          10|
|name2|14.57|    2.0|          10|
|name3| 2.21|    0.0|           0|
|name4| 8.76|    1.0|           5|
|name5|18.71|    3.0|          15|
+-----+-----+-------+------------+
```

## EDIT: Correcting the score buckets:

```
# Not dynamic, but please try to figure out this business logic according to your use-case
df_buck = df_buck.withColumn("correct_buckets", F.when(df_buck.Score-df_buck.score_bucket > 5/2, F.col("score_bucket") + 5).otherwise(F.col("score_bucket"))).drop("buckets", "score_bucket")
```

Now **output** is as expected:

```
+-----+-----+---------------+
| Name|Score|correct_buckets|
+-----+-----+---------------+
|name1|11.23|             10|
|name2|14.57|             15|
|name3| 2.21|              0|
|name4| 8.76|             10|
|name5|18.71|             20|
+-----+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: Really good post @pisall : I am able to run the code fine till the last line `df_buck.show()` . When `df_buck.show()` tries to execute `df_buck = df_buck.withColumn("score_bucket", udf_foo("buckets"))` , I get the following error: ```      19     df_buck = df_buck.withColumn( "kk_bucket", udf_nearest_bin("buckets") )
---> 20     df_buck.show()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))```

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy Not able to understand, that is very ittle information. I would need the error from after `Py4JError` or `AnalysisException` or something. You can add it to your question if you like using an edit

Comment: I was able to solve the error. Thanks for this awesome answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can also `pandas_udf` although I'd suggest you test out the speed and memory consumption as you scale up

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(["name_"+str(i) for i in range(1,6)], [11.23, 14.57, 2.21, 8.76, 18.71]), ["Name", "Score"])

bin_array = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20])

@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def find_nearest(value):
    res = bin_array[np.newaxis, :] - value.values[:, np.newaxis]
    ret_vals = [bin_array[np.argmin(np.abs(i))] for i in res]
    return pd.Series(ret_vals)

df.withColumn('v2', find_nearest(df.Score)).show()
```

Output

```
+------+-----+----+
|  Name|Score|  v2|
+------+-----+----+
|name_1|11.23|10.0|
|name_2|14.57|15.0|
|name_3| 2.21| 0.0|
|name_4| 8.76|10.0|
|name_5|18.71|20.0|
+------+-----+----+
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to see how the function scales with larger data?